# Maven creating layered jar architecture without any specific config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am working with Docker and I would like to create layered jar architecture. I have this pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sc</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>eureka-server</name>
    <description>Eureka server for SC client</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Based on various articles online if I wanted this to be layered jar architecture I would change this snippet in plugin section

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <layers>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </layers>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Even without this snippet I am having this layered jar architecture. Output of command
**java -Djarmode=layertools -jar eureka-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar list** is these four layers:

1. dependencies
2. spring-boot-loader
3. snapshot-dependencies
4. application

So my question is how is it possible that I got layers without this specific snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question by now. As someone who's just discovered layered jars and trying to work it into an existing maven project, I came across this snippet from [this springboot blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/creating-efficient-docker-images-with-spring-boot-2-3):

[image: layered jars are by default since springboot 2.4]

Comment: Yep, I have found it also a bit later. From version Spring Boot 2.4 layering is enabled by default. Thanks for the comment :). I will mark the answer as an accepted one.